# pkill given process depending on input arguments

Tags: bash, input, parameters, pkill

I have a python process running, called `test.py` that I run from a bash script with input parameters.

```
$PWD/test.py -s $symbol -folder $folder -n $name -d $name
```

Once running `ps -elf | grep test.py`, the process appears with the parameters.

I am trying, within that same bash script, to kill this process given the input arguments:

```
pkill -f 'test.py -s $symbol -folder $folder -n $name -d $name'
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

What is the correct syntax? Do I need to add parentheses `()` or brackets `{}` somewhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-should-i-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: use double quotes instead of single quotes in your pkill command

Comment: @Aserre super helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Aserre mentioned in the comments, you'll need to use double quotes instead of single quotes in your `pkill` command so that the value of the shell variables is replaced in the string.

Also, take into account that `pkill` sends `SIGTERM` by default. Therefore, `test.py` should have a signal handler to shutdown when it receives SIGTERM. If `test.py` doesn't have a signal handler, it will ignore the signal and continue to live. If that is the case, use `pkill -9`, which will kill `ptest.py` since signal 9 can't be ignored:

```
pkill -9 -f "test.py -s $symbol -folder $folder -n $name -d $name"
```

Finally, I'm assuming that `test.py` runs as a daemon or somehow runs in the background. Otherwise, your bash script will wait until it exits before it continues. If `test.py` is not a daemon, your bash script can run it in the background. Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

symbol=pi
folder=/tmp
name=john
$PWD/test.py -s $symbol -folder $folder -n $name -d $name &
pid=$!
echo "killer: started test.py ($pid)..."

sleep 5
echo "killer: killing test.py..."

# you may use -9 instead of -SIGTERM
pkill -SIGTERM -f "test.py -s $symbol -folder $folder -n $name -d $name"
wait $pid
echo "killer: test.py is dead; exiting..."
```